# Any point using SVG Web, if not supporting IE7 and 8?

Tags: cross-browser, svg

Is there any point in using [SVG Web](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), if I render SVG only for browsers that support SVG anyway? (IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Opera.)

Perhaps SVG Web fixes/works-around some browser inconsistencies? (E.g. different SVG API:s or browser bugs, like jQuery does)

((*Background:* I already use SVG Web, and wonder if I should attempt to remove it from my webapp, it's 100k minified. For IE 7 and 8, I use PNG images instead.))

Comment: you'll need it if IE9 runs in quirks mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not really.
2. AFAIK it doesn't do that, unless you force all browsers to use the flash renderer, which seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Thanks! Then I'll go ahead and attempt to throw away SVG Web from my web app :-). Actually, in my case, the Flash renderer was/seemed so slow so I never used it (I fill up almost the entire page with SVG stuff).

Comment: (I use SVG Web no more (since a month ago), and everything works fine :-)   )